# tomcat странности с кодировкой при деплое war на сервер

Tags: java, jsp, servlet, tomcat

При деплое проекта из IDE (Idea) всё работает правильно, кодировка отображается верно. Но при упаковке проекта в war maven'ом и деплое на tomcat происходит странная вещь: часть строк отображается не корректно. 
Например в сервлете я читаю строку из файла, добавляю в неё символы с клавиатуры, передаю через request предварительно сменив кодировку на UTF-8 getWritter'ом в JSP, и на выходе та часть строк, что вычитана из файла отображается нормально, а та часть, которая введена с клавиатуры - нет.
На всех JSP кодировка установлена UTF8, в каждом сервлете, во всех методах на все параметры также установлена UTF8. Фильтр изменяющий кодировку замаплен на все сервлеты. Файлы классов также в UTF8. В чем проблема может быть, товарищи? :(

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, минимальный компилируемый код, демонстрирующий проблему. Это означает, что код должен компилироваться и в нём не должно быть лишних элементов.

Answer (score 5):

Согласно [документации](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q8):

Для полной поддержки кодировки `UTF-8` необходимо:

1. Установить `URIEncoding="UTF-8"` в `<Connector>` в файле `server.xml`.

Пример:

```
 <Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="8192"
      maxThreads="150" minSpareThreads="25" maxSpareThreads="75"
      enableLookups="false" redirectPort="8443" acceptCount="100"
      connectionTimeout="20000" disableUploadTimeout="true"
      URIEncoding="UTF-8"
  />
```

2. Использовать [фильтр](http://wiki.apache.org/tomcat/FAQ/CharacterEncoding#Q3) для установки кодировки `UTF-8`.
3. Изменить все `JSP` страницы и добавить кодировку в `contentType`. Например, использовать `<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" %>` для стандартных `JSP` страниц и `<jsp:directive.page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />` для страниц, использующих XML-синтаксис.
4. Изменить все свои сервлеты и явно установить `content type`. Например, использовать `response.setContentType("text/html; charset=UTF-8")` или  `response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8").`
5. Изменить все библиотеки, которые могут генерировать контент (Velocity, Freemarker, т.д.), чтобы они использовали `UTF-8` и явно указывали `UTF-8` в поле `content type` в ответе, который они создают.
6. Отключить различные фильтры, которые могут считывать параметры запроса перед фильтром, преобразывающим кодировку.

Для более конкретного ответа необходимо больше деталей.

Comment: Я вам безмерно благодарен, ваши советы помогли мне углубиться в проблеме и найти решение :)

Answer (score 1):

Может кто тоже столкнется из-за нехватки опыта и знаний:

Проблема оказалась, как ни странно в Мавене, в настройках параметра упаковки в war нужно явно указать кодировку UTF-8 если ваш проект в данной кодировке. Это объясняет и то, что при деплое из Idea было все нормально, так как деплоится все как есть.